# random array generation in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to write a simple function that generates an array with random integers.

I encountered with an interesting thing, when I run this program outputs -each cout 
statements- seem the same.

However, when I am debugging and watching it step by step array values are changing.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

```
void generateRandomArray( int *&inputArray, int size){

    if(inputArray != NULL){
        delete []inputArray;

    }

    //create a new array
    inputArray = new int [size];

    //fill with random numbers   
    srand(unsigned (time (NULL)));
    for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)     
        inputArray[i] = (rand() % 100) ;

}
int main(){

    //Variables
    int *inputArray = NULL;
    int size;


    //Test
    size = 10;

    //first call
    generateRandomArray( inputArray, size);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++){
        cout << inputArray[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "------------------" << endl;

    //second call
    generateRandomArray( inputArray, size);

    //output is the same with previous
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++){
        cout << inputArray[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Call `srand` once.

Comment: Call `srand(time(NULL));` just after you start main.

Comment: Don't use that legacy C stuff. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: Once it works. Goto [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get input on better techniques.

Comment: If you single-step through the code really fast while debugging, you'll observe the same result as without the debugger attached :)

Comment: Read about the new [pseudo-random classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) and [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) and [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate).

Comment: @sp2danny: The parameter is a reference to a pointer. (Types are read right to left). A pointer to a reference is illegal and will not compile.

Comment: BTW, use `std::vector` instead of raw array.

Comment: but what's the reason of the difference btw debugging output and actual output?

Comment: the time it takes, srand the next second will produce a new value

Comment: while not debugging both calls to `time(NULL)` happen within one timer tick, hence same sequence is generated for every call. While debugging, some time passes between calls, so different sequence is generated.

Answer (score 0):

The program runs too fast, `srand(unsigned (time (NULL)));` will get a seed having the same seconds (since epoch). Hence, the rand sequences are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if the calls to `srand` all happen withing the same second, the generator will be seeded with the same values and so generate the same sequence, always.

When you're debugging it will be slower, and allow time to pass and have different seed for the generator. When not debugging the time between calls will be too fast.

Don't call `srand` more than once, unless you know what you're doing. Put it at the start of the `main` function, and don't call it again.

Answer (score 0):

Call `srand(time(NULL))` and it will seed the current time and make a random number from it. Since time is changing all the time, it will give you a different number every time.

Answer (score 0):

With C++11, you may use something like: (https://ideone.com/EIb0nY)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> generateRandomArray(std::default_random_engine& generator, int size)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1, 100);
    std::vector<int> res(size);

    for (auto& e : res) {
        e = distribution(generator);
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    const int size = 10;

    //first call
    for (auto e : generateRandomArray(generator, size)) {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "------------------" << std::endl;

    //second call
    for (auto e : generateRandomArray(generator2, size)) {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That use the new *random* facilities.
It avoids manual memory management (with `std::vector`).